# Как проверить строку на наличие символов?

Tags: c++

В общем мне нужно реализовать проверку строки на наличие символов так, чтобы можно было что бы в строке были буквы и цифры но запрещено было наличие других символов

```
cout << "Name the Group(use letters and digits): ";
cin >> title;
while(/*здесь хочу вставить условие*/) {
    cout << "You can't use symbols except letters and digits, try again: ";
    cin >> title;
}
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения примените.

Comment: [isalnum](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем парится, если можно покороче, используя регулрние выражения))

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <regex>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    regex r("[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]*");
    
    string title;
    cin >> title;

    while (!regex_match(title, r))
    {
        cout << "You can't use symbols except letters and digits, try again: ";
        cin >> title;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD:**
Стало интересно, какой вариант производительней, мой(с помощью `regex`) или автора самодельной функции **@n1tr0xs**. Вот такие результаты:

- **@ТарасПрогер** : *0.188461     сек.*
- **@n1tr0xs**           : *0.0432593 сек.*

9999 раз, и среднее арифметическое. 2 вариант работает быстрее в *4.36* раза. Правда, это все цветочки. Нужно использовать более понятный и удобный вариант как `regex`.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: Если есть желание, то вот ещё одна [самодельная функция](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08e3e72c347333bd) для тестирования.

Comment: Хорошо (и ещё 8 символов)

Comment: А что делает эта функция? Что связано наверно с вопросом Дмитрия

Comment: а зачем столько пробелов в регулярке? "что бы в строке были буквы и цифры" - по вашей регулярке проходят и пустая строка, и строка длиной один символ.

Comment: а, простите. Думал с пробелами воспринимается лучше. Спасибо!

Comment: @ТарасПрогер, как по мне -- определённо лучше)

Comment: regex вообще лучше не использовать (слишком ненадежный прием программирования,  не стоит привыкать к нему)

Comment: @avp, хорошо, буду знать, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3):

Можно так, например:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

bool is_valid(char* str, char* alph){
    int alph_len = strlen(alph), str_len = strlen(str);
    for(int i=0; i<str_len; ++i){
        bool res = false;
        for(int j=0; j<alph_len; ++j){
            if(str[i] == alph[j]){
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!res)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(){
    char title[100];
    char allowed_chars[] = "abcdefg";

    cout << "Name the Group(use letters and digits): ";
    cin >> title;
    while(!is_valid(title, allowed_chars)){
        cout << "You can't use symbols except letters and digits, try again: ";
        cin >> title;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поздравляю, Ваш вариант работает быстрее чем мой в 4.36 раза быстрее))

Comment: Возможно, можно сделать еще быстрее (без внутреннего цикла), если вместо перебора допустимых символов, проверять его наличие в диапазоне требуемых символов в таблице кодировки. Тогда целый цикл заменится условным оператором. Хоть это и применимо только к конкретной задаче, а этот метод более общий.

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<strlen(alph); ++j){` - многократное вычисление размера алфавита за линейное время. Вы серьёзно?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не стал выносить в переменную, так как зачастую компилятор сам оптимизирует это вычисление (выносит в "переменную").

Comment: [man isalnum](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum)?